# Vbnet Sql incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

```
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-3H4F5GB\MURATS;Initial Catalog=CRM;Integrated Security=True"

        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Firma  SET (Sektor = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', Tip = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', Telefon = '" & MaskedTextBox1.Text & "', Web = '" & TextBox2.Text & "', Adres = '" & RichTextBox2.Text & "', OSB = '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', PR = '" & ComboBox4.Text & "', Sehir = '" & ComboBox5.Text & "', Ulke = '" & ComboBox6.Text & "', Note = '" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', Durum = '" & ComboBox7.Text & "', Email ='" & TextBox3.Text & "') WHERE Firma = '" & ComboBox8.Text & "'"**

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Insert Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: ı couldnt find the problem part I couldnt fix it and typed as below too

Comment: remove the bracket after `SET` and before `Where`. Also you need to parameterize your query. Current code is open to sql injection.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: abi did you get this problem sorted?

Comment: Werdna I couldnt understand

Comment: Your code is wide open to a sql injection hack.  Never construct sql queries using string concatenation, especially if part of the string comes from user input.  You should use a parameterized query instead.

Comment: Never ever glue strings together to make SQL,  This is just one of the issues that SQL Parameters will prevent

Answer (score 0):

Your error is clearly on this line

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Firma  SET (Sektor = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', Tip = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', Telefon = '" & MaskedTextBox1.Text & "', Web = '" & TextBox2.Text & "', Adres = '" & RichTextBox2.Text & "', OSB = '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', PR = '" & ComboBox4.Text & "', Sehir = '" & ComboBox5.Text & "', Ulke = '" & ComboBox6.Text & "', Note = '" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', Durum = '" & ComboBox7.Text & "', Email ='" & TextBox3.Text & "') WHERE Firma = '" & ComboBox8.Text & "'"**
```

You have to remove the `()` from the `Update` statement to be like the below

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Firma  SET Sektor = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', Tip = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', Telefon = '" & MaskedTextBox1.Text & "', Web = '" & TextBox2.Text & "', Adres = '" & RichTextBox2.Text & "', OSB = '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', PR = '" & ComboBox4.Text & "', Sehir = '" & ComboBox5.Text & "', Ulke = '" & ComboBox6.Text & "', Note = '" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', Durum = '" & ComboBox7.Text & "', Email ='" & TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE Firma = '" & ComboBox8.Text & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

remove your open and close parenthesis on:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Firma  SET (Sektor = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', Tip = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', Telefon = '" & MaskedTextBox1.Text & "', Web = '" & TextBox2.Text & "', Adres = '" & RichTextBox2.Text & "', OSB = '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', PR = '" & ComboBox4.Text & "', Sehir = '" & ComboBox5.Text & "', Ulke = '" & ComboBox6.Text & "', Note = '" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', Durum = '" & ComboBox7.Text & "', Email ='" & TextBox3.Text & "')
```

answer

```
 cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Firma  SET Sektor = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', Tip = '" & ComboBox2.Text & "', Telefon = '" & MaskedTextBox1.Text & "', Web = '" & TextBox2.Text & "', Adres = '" & RichTextBox2.Text & "', OSB = '" & ComboBox3.Text & "', PR = '" & ComboBox4.Text & "', Sehir = '" & ComboBox5.Text & "', Ulke = '" & ComboBox6.Text & "', Note = '" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', Durum = '" & ComboBox7.Text & "', Email ='" & TextBox3.Text & "'
```

and some addition try to learn to use parametized queries comment if you want to learn.